# Installing powershell module using packer powershell provisioner (azure-arm)

Tags: powershell, packer

I have a very simple packer configuration to build a windows 2019 image, where I am trying to install some Powershell modules before I can do some other work with those modules. But the provisioning is just hanging at install-module step. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
{
"min_packer_version": "1.4.0",
"variables": {
  "client_id": "{{env `ARM_CLIENT_ID`}}",
  "client_secret": "{{env `ARM_CLIENT_SECRET`}}",
  "tenant_id": "{{env `ARM_TENANT_ID`}}",
  "subscription_id": "{{env `ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID`}}",
  "buildkite_agent_token": "{{env `BUILDKITE_AGENT_TOKEN` }}"
  },
"builders": [{
    "type": "azure-arm",
    "client_id": "{{user `client_id`}}",
    "client_secret": "{{user `client_secret`}}",
    "tenant_id": "{{user `tenant_id`}}",
    "subscription_id": "{{user `subscription_id`}}",
    "managed_image_resource_group_name": "packer-mgmt-rg",
    "managed_image_name": "test-windows-image",
    "os_type": "Windows",
    "image_publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
    "image_offer": "WindowsServer",
    "image_sku": "2019-Datacenter",
    "communicator": "winrm",
    "location": "EastUs2",
    "vm_size": "Standard_DS2_v2",
    "winrm_insecure": true,
    "winrm_timeout": "5m",
    "winrm_use_ssl": true,
    "winrm_username": "packer",
    "winrm_password": "Packer_11#"
  }
],
"provisioners": [
    
    {
      "type":"powershell", 
      "elevated_user": "packer",
      "elevated_password": "Packer_11#", 
      "inline": [
           "Install-Module VSSetup -Scope CurrentUser -Force"  
      ]
    },
    {
      "type":"powershell", 
      "script": "./scripts/sysprep.ps1"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Can the machine executing packer talk to the VMs in which packer provisions? Not via API but via the sockets? I guess Win32-OpenSSH also uses port 22 like linux..

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance you'll have to change the PowerShell gallery repository to trusted so that it doesn't prompt when you install prior to installing your module.

```
Set-PSRepository -Name 'PSGallery' -InstallationPolicy Trusted
```

Probably worth setting it back to the default setting after too

Answer (score 0):

Install-Module VSSetup needs the nuget PackageProvider thus if you install it before Install-Module it should work.

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force
Install-Module VSSetup -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

At least in my case where I'm using Packer Install-PackageProvider before Install-Module solved this issue.